# Prove that series both converge at the same time

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$f$ is a positive function strictly increasing on the interval$[1;+\infty)$, and $f(x) \rightarrow +\infty$ with $x\rightarrow + \infty$. The task is to prove, that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{f(n)}~~and~~\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{-1}(n)}{n^2}$$
both converge at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: What does $f^{-1}(n)$ mean if $n$ is not in the range?

Comment: What does "at the same time" mean?

Comment: @SimpleArt it probably means that they other _both converge_ or _both diverge_.

Comment: Have you tried the comparison test to the p-series?